# Sed to show only matching group is not working

Tags: regex, sed

I make this regular inside a file and it shows line:

```
sed -n "/href=\"\(openswitch-disk-image-genericx86-64-0.1.0\+.*\.tar\.gz\)\"/p" index.html
```

But if I do this it shows nothing:

```
sed -n "s/href=\"\(openswitch-disk-image-genericx86-64-0.1.0\+.*\.tar\.gz\)\"/\1/g" index.html
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: replace `g` with `p` at the last..

Comment: It shows the line and not the group. I only need the part that matches with the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using perl -nle like this:

perl -nle 'print $1 if /href="(openswitch-disk-image-genericx86-64-0.1.0+[0-9]+.tar.gz)"/' index.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to bend sed to do that. However grep's `-o` flag is made just for this

```
grep -o "openswitch-disk-image-genericx86-64-0.1.0\+.*\.tar\.gz" index.html
```

It's not clear if you want "one or more zeros" or "zero followed by plus"

Comment: I'm looking for the plus sign not more zeros